# Why are realizations of the Stochastic Schrödinger Equation (apparently) not normalized?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, schroedinger-equation, stochastic-processes, quantum-measurements

In "A Straightforward Introduction to Continuous Quantum Measurement" the Stochastic Schrodinger Equation (SSE) for continuous measurement of the observable $X$ is given as $$ d |\psi\rangle = -k (X- \langle X \rangle )^2 + \sqrt{2 k}(X- \langle X \rangle)dW  \tag{1}\label{1}$$ where $k$ is just a time-independent parameter that depends on the details of the measurement.

Using Eq. 1,  I find that continuous measurement of a normalized qubit $|\phi \rangle $, (with no relative phase), for the observable $X= \sigma_z$, produces the SSE in Eq. 2.

$$ |\phi \rangle = \pmatrix{a \\ b} \quad a,b \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$ d|\phi\rangle=\pmatrix{da \\ db}  =\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -4 k a b^4 \\
 -4 k b^5+8 k b^3-4 k b \\
\end{array}
\right) dt + \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{k} a b^2 \\
 2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{k} b^3-2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt{k} b \\
\end{array}
\right) dW.
\tag{2}\label{2} $$

However, picking a noise realization $dW(t)= 0 \space \forall t$ and then solving the leftover (non-stochastic) differential equation produces an SDE realization that is not normalized. It was my understanding that the SSE should preserve state normalization (unlike its linear counterpart!).

Is it that only $\langle a(t) \rangle^2 +\langle b(t) \rangle^2 = 1$, with individual realizations free to be unnormalized? Or have I just made a mistake in Eq. 2 somewhere?